# How to use Google App Scripts with Auto Trigger feature on Google spreadsheet to cover a large Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a 3.5 GB size google drive. I have a container bound Google App Script, which scans the entire drive and lists files that satisfy a certain criteria. To avoid timeout, i use auto trigger feature.The trigger is activated every 5 minutes and each time the script is executed for 4 minutes. I find that the script takes roughly 2 to 3 hours to parse the entire drive. I need to use the script on a much larger google drive. I checked the quota for triggers and find that it is 20 /script/user. I am unsure if this will suffice to scan the large drive. How can i ensure timeout doesn't occur or how do i continue from where i left off in case of timeout? The requirement is that the script should scan all the files and folders in a very large Google drive which may not be parsed within the available script execution time quota.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Handling in Classic Asp without timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200028/error-handling-in-classic-asp-without-timeout-error)

Comment: Thank you for responding @albertovielma. I know it will timeout before completing the entire Drive. I need to know if there is a way to resume from where i left to complete the entire scan